# React Component - Input Fields from Form Not Using UseState Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import AddRecordButton from './AddRecordButton';

const AddRecordForm=()=>{
const [content, setContent]=useState([]);
const [artist_name, setartist_name] = useState('');
const [album_name, setalbum_name] = useState('');
const [album_price, setalbum_price] = useState('');
const [album_img, setalbum_img] = useState('');


const handleArtistNameChange=(e)=> setartist_name(e.target.value);
const handleAlbumNameChange=(e)=> setalbum_name(e.target.value);
const handleAlbumPriceChange=(e)=> setalbum_price(e.target.value);
const handleAlbumImg=(e)=> setalbum_img(e.target.value);

const addContent = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const newContent = [{artist_name: artist_name, album_name: album_name, album_price: album_price, album_img: album_img}, ...content];
    setContent(newContent);
    setartist_name('');
    setalbum_name('');
    setalbum_price('');
    setalbum_img('');
    console.log(newContent);
};

return (
<form className="record-form" onSubmit={addContent}>
    <label htmlFor="album-img">Album Art URL:</label>
    <input id ="album-img" type="text" value={album_img} onChange={handleAlbumImg}/>
    <br></br>

    <label htmlFor="artist-name">Artist Name:</label>
    <input id="artist-name" type="text" value={artist_name} onChange={handleArtistNameChange}/>
    <br></br>

    <label htmlFor="album-name">Album Name:</label>
    <input id="album-name" type="text" value={album_name} onChange={handleAlbumNameChange}/>
    <br></br>

    <label htmlFor="album-price">Album Price:</label>
    <input id="album-price" type="text" value={album_price} onChange={handleAlbumPriceChange}/>
    <br></br>

</form>
)
}

export default AddRecordForm;
```

When I put data into my input fields and click the Add button, it is supposed to add a new record with the data I put into the input fields. It is not doing this when I click the button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abYLS.png)

Comment: Where is your Add button? I just see 4 text inputs in your form.

Comment: Hey @Christine Hoang, It seems you imported `AddRecordButton` but haven't actually used it in the form. Add the missing code. Please let us know if problem still persists.

Comment: your code is working fine, just add button and useState import https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/muddy-night-dgf8l2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A18%2C8

Answer (score 0):

You need to add button and provide the Type as submit, it will run properly